# Can't repair GRUB

Tags: grub2

I'm trying to repair my GRUB after Windows 7 installation.

I have **64bit and 32bit live Ubuntu CDs + [Super Grub Disk (Rescatux)](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/) + [Boot-Repair-Disk](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/)** . I'm following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/88432/17345)'s steps . But in 6th step I'm getting

`/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error while loading shared libraries: libdevmapper.so.1.02.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32` after executing `update-grub`command.

And then I tried to use [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) . Firstly tried *Recommended repair* and it's finished successfully but when I restart there isn't boot menu. And then next time I hold Left Shift while booting. Still it's booting Windows automatically.

And then I tried to use *Advanced repair* . Same results. This is my Boot-Repair logs : http://paste.ubuntu.com/936178/

I need specific answers for my system. Thank you.

**Note :**

> My installed Ubuntu system is 64 bit and I have 64bit and 32 bit Live CDs

**Note 2**

> (after booting with a 32bit Live CD) (look at **Note 3 for 64bit Live CD results**)
>
> `file /lib/libdevmapper.so.1.02.1` -> `/lib/libdevmapper.so.1.02.1: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped`
>
> `file /usr/sbin/grub-probe` -> `/usr/sbin/grub-probe: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, stripped`

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mkdir /mnt/ubusda3
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sda3 /mnt/ubusda3
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ file /mnt/ubusda3/sbin/init
/mnt/ubusda3/sbin/init: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, stripped
```

**Note 3**

> (after booting with a 64bit Live CD)
>
> `file /lib/libdevmapper.so.1.02.1` -> `/lib/libdevmapper.so.1.02.1: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped`
>
> `file /usr/sbin/grub-probe` -> `/usr/sbin/grub-probe: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, stripped`

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo su
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# mkdir /mnt/ubusda3
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# mount -t ext4 /dev/sda3 /mnt/ubusda3
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# file /mnt/ubusda3/sbin/init
/mnt/ubusda3/sbin/init: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, stripped
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# file /mnt/ubusda3/lib/libdevmapper.so.1.02.1
/mnt/ubusda3/lib/libdevmapper.so.1.02.1: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped
```

Comment: It looks like your installed system is in fact, not 64 bit.

Comment: @psusi , why? how?

Comment: Actually it looks like it might just some files that are 32bit.  See what `file /lib/libdevmapper.so.1.02.1` and `file /usr/sbin/grub-probe` say ( while within the chroot ).

Comment: @psusi , please check my **Note 2**

Comment: First you said you were using a 64 bit livecd, now 32.  Which is it?  You need to use the 64 bit one.

Comment: @psusi , i have 32 bit AND 64 bit live cd's. You said `your system 32bit` because of this i tried with 32Bit livecd.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3172/discussion-between-psusi-and-eray)

Comment: @psusi ? chat please

Comment: it seems like the installed system is LVM based

Answer (score 2):

#### Drat!

I finally got a multi-boot of versions of Ubuntu and a Windows 7 install working in a VirtualBox Virtual Machine so I could experiment with the repair tools. It turns out my original suggestion was wrong and did not work as I thought it would. :-(

So ... starting over ...

While I intend to experiment more with a VM to learn more about the various tools such as the [Boot-Repair](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) tool or using a Live CD and `chroot` and to reinstall GRUB, I figured the most expedient thing I could offer now would be to sketch out one way to allow booting from Windows into the GRUB menu.

I am not suggesting this as "the" final solution. But it should at least enable booting up the Ubuntu partition again which also, I think, opens up other repair options.

Also, having tried it on the VM, I have some confidence that this should work. (Mentally crossing fingers here ...)

#### Using EasyBCD 2.1.2 to Boot to GRUB from Windows Boot Menu

1. Start up Windows. Then open the [EasyBCD 2.1.2 page](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) in a browser and use the *[Download free for limited, non-commercial use](http://neosmart.net/download.php?id=1)* link to download and install EasyBCD.
   *Note:* This link is underneath the *Buy Now* button towards the bottom of the page.
   While they prompt for a name & email, you are **not** required to enter them to do the download.
2. Open the EasyBCD program and select **Add New Entry** from the sidebar on the left.
3. Select the rightmost tab, **NeoGrub**, under "*Operating Systems*" and click the <kbd>**Install**</kbd> button.
   *Note:*  This adds the NeoGrub bootloader code to your `C:\` directory.
   You should see the file `NeoGrub` and the directory `NST` in `C:\` if the install worked correctly.
4. Select the **Linux/BSD** tab. Choose the type of GRUB your install uses (e.g. GRUB 2) and, optionally, edit the name of the
     entry you are about to add to the Windows Boot menu.
5. Click the <kbd>**Add Entry**</kbd> button to add an entry to boot Linux (GRUB menu) to the Windows boot menu.
6. Select **Edit Boot Menu** from the sidebar to review your changes.
   *Note:* You can delete the entry for **NeoGrub Bootloader** if you wish.
   It was added when you installed the NeoGrub Bootloader in step (3). You need the bootloader but you do not need a boot menu entry for it. You only need the entry added in step (5).
7. Save your changes and reboot. When the Windows boot menu appears, select the entry you added to boot Linux. After a slight delay the GNU GRUB boot menu should appear.

Comment: thanks for your answer ! What do you mean with `Boot-Repair-Disk`? Is it this : http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1831869 ?

Comment: i just tried http://www.supergrubdisk.org/ but in Order Hard Disks screen there is no harddisk. So i got errors. I will try Boot-Repair-Disk now.

Comment: i tried it.  But after choosing Ubuntu, when i restart my PC i got `Operation System Not Found` error .

Comment: just tried it. It booting Windows 7 automatically. There is no boot menu, again. http://paste.ubuntu.com/936782/

Comment: for your update : i'm getting this error : `/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error while loading shared libraries: libdevmapper.so.1.02.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32` after update-grub

Comment: i tried with internet connection. Nothing changed.

Comment: i'm getting this error while booting Boot-Repair-Cd . What's it's mean ? http://www.iimmgg.com/image/f228dbc5fff20a797d45c30983c9eb3d

Answer (score 1):

Boot into the live CD and try these commands (only if you already have Ubuntu installed). This is for Grub2.

You will need to find your partition with ubuntu on it and replace /dev/sdAX. This can be done with the following command `sudo fdisk -l` - and then choose the partition 'Linux'

```
sudo su
mkdir /mnt/root
mount -t ext4 /dev/sdAX /mnt/root
mount -t proc none /mnt/root/proc
mount -o bind /dev /mnt/root/dev
mount -o bind /sys /mnt/root/sys
chroot /mnt/root /bin/bash
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Hayes,  i'm getting command not found for *install-grub* and *install_device not specified* for *grub-install*.

Comment: Sorry, definitely use grub-install. I don't know which of the following it is exactly but you can try 'hd0', '/dev/sda' or some other name of your hard drive. I would start with hd0 - I think that's what I've done on my machine. That would make final syntax 'sudo grub-install hd0'. Easy.