# can i use windows boot manager to boot into ubuntu 11.10

Tags: dual-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set Windows to boot as the default in the boot loader?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader)

i want to use windows boot manager instead of Grub to boot into ubuntu 11.10

1.Grub looks something like this:

ubuntu

ubuntu(recovery mode)

memory test

memory test

windows 7

2.windows boot manager looks like this:

windows 7

ubuntu

so windows boot manager looks more neat than Grub, my problem is that i forgot how to install ubuntu 11.10 such that it uses windows boot manager to boot with windows 7 as the first option on the boot menu.any help?

Answer (score 1):

Changing from grub to Windows boot manager is a bit complicated. You should stick to Grub to avoid complications.If you really, **really** want to change then look below.

There is  a programm for windows called easy bcd. Install it when running windows and the proceed a described in the following link:

[how to use easy bcd](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/use-the-windows-bootloader-to-dual-boot-windows-vista-and-ubuntu.html)

Or

see [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/port25/archive/2006/10/13/http-port25-technet-com-archive-2006-10-12-windows-and-linux-integration-3a00-a-conversation-with-the-author-aspx.aspx) link for an another way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to modify the Windows boot manager to add an entry to boot Ubuntu. But another option is to use [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) to boot GRUB and then boot Ubuntu. I tried to outline how to do this in [**this answer**](https://askubuntu.com/a/123320/52923).

Note that this does **NOT** boot Windows directly. Instead, the Windows boot manager boots GRUB so you go from the Windows menu to the GRUB menu.

While I don't know if it is even possible to boot Ubuntu directly from the Windows loader, I am sure this is not a good idea. Mostly because Ubuntu does not know how to (or want to)  update anything other than GRUB when a updated Linux kernel is installed.